# How to get characters read from the keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I am trying to get the characters read from the keyboard into some variable for further manipulation. I have the following list that I wish to recognize if entered by a user.

**List of keyboard entries:**

- letters
- `[`
- `]`
- `~`
- `^`
- numbers

**Part of the code:**

```
 void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
       string test = e.KeyCode.ToString();
```

Here numbers, letters and square brackets work but the `^` which require shift key is read incorrectly. For eg. it reads ^ which is on key 6 as a string value of 6 and not ^ as it should be. Here are the other readings

- [ = OemOpenBracket,
- ] = Oem6,
- ~ = OemTilde,
- ^ = D6.

So D6 is not making senseAny help would be appreciated.

Thanks

AA

Answer (score 3):

You need to check to see if [e.Shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.shift.aspx) is true, in addition to just checking the KeyCode property.

Comment: okay. Here's what I have. It reads [ --> OemOpenBracket, ] --> Oem6, ~ --> OemTilde, ^ --> D6. So D6 is not making sense.

Comment: Characters and numbers get converted to upper character so i shows as I which should not be the case

Comment: BTW e.Shift is never true - even when I use shift key

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to do it this way:

```
private readonly string VALID_KEYS = "[]~^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

private void txtBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (VALID_KEYS.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) != -1 || e.KeyChar == (char)8)
         e.Handled = false;
    else
         e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Actually I want the combination of letters, numbers and special characters (as listed above) entered by the user. I am checking and I need to append these to my variable. So I need to evaluate what was wntered by the use r which will be used for further evaluations

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help...

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Shift | Keys.D6:
                    //Your code
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Thanks,
Ram